# ffmpeg add loop to this line of code i have

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

windows 7 64 bit running latest ffmpeg command-line.

```
ffmpeg -i "song.mp4" -i "2.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=3000|60000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" -vcodec copy -y "output1.mp4"
```

I want to loop the 2.mp3 all the way till the video ends.

The 2.mp3 finishes after xxx time in 2.mp3 so I wish to loop it instead of how do I add a loop to this.

Comment: Welcome! It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you saying that `2.mp3` is shorter than `song.mp4` and you want to loop the `mp3`? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at the `aloop`-filter.

```
ffmpeg -i "song.mp4" -i "2.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]aloop=loop=-1[al];[al]adelay=3000|60000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" -vcodec copy -y "output1.mp4"
```

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aloop

And then you will probably want to limit the song.mp4, so we are using the `duration` option of `amix`, to tell it to limit by the first input given. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix

```
ffmpeg -i "song.mp4" -i "2.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]aloop=loop=-1[al];[al]adelay=3000|60000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix=duration=first" -vcodec copy -y "output1.mp4"
```

Since I am not sure which of the two files you want to loop and don't know if you want to loop before or after the delay you might need to adjust the order of filters.